# How can I take a picture from screen?

Tags: c#, screen, screen-capture

I want to write a program that shows one PC's screen to the others... something like presentation systems. how can i take a picture from current screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.NET exposes this functionality via the Screen (*System.Windows.Forms*) class.

```
     // the surface that we are focusing upon
     Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();

     // capture all screens in Windows
     foreach (Screen screen in Screen.AllScreens)
     {
        // increase the Rectangle to accommodate the bounds of all screens
        rect = Rectangle.Union(rect, screen.Bounds);
     }

     // create a new image that will store the capture
     Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(rect.Width, rect.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

     using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
     {
        // use GDI+ to copy the contents of the screen into the bitmap
        g.CopyFromScreen(rect.X, rect.Y, 0, 0, rect.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
     }

     // bitmap now has the screen capture
```

Comment: Thank you for your help... And is there any other way to make it faster? coz copying from screen should be slow for my project...

Comment: GDI+ methods are not the fastest in the world by any metric.  What are you intending to do with this?